# Why is a DC to AC inverter called "inverter"?

Tags: power-supply, power, device

A device to convert direct current to grid level alternating current seems to be called "inverter".

It's typically called like that when used in a solar power system.

Why is it called inverter? Does it invert anything?

Is a small DC to AC converter in the range of 1 W also called inverter? And if not: why?

Comment: I'd prefer the term converter but possibly the marketing people had a say in things.

Comment: It "inverts" the flow of current: in DC you have two terminals and the current only flows in one direction; in AC you still have two terminals, but current flows in both directions

Comment: Could be some carryover from the vacuum tube days, or earlier. Like cascode.

Answer (score 7):

> **Origins of the Inverter**
>
> David Prince probably coined the term
>   inverter. It is unlikely that any living person
>   can now , establish with certainty that
>   Prince (or anyone else) was the originator
>   of this commonly used engineering term.
>   However, in 1925 Prince did publish an
>   article in the GE Review titled “The Inverter”. His article contains nearly all
>   important elements required by modern
>   inverters and is the earliest such publication
>   to use that term in the open literature.
>
> The idea of using grid control in combination with phase retard to modulate
>   AC power originated with others about
>   four years earlier. However, Prince appears to have been the individual who
>   took Alexanderson’s expression “inverted rectification” and created a single
>   English-language word inverter. It conveys the idea of a rectifier except functioning in an inverted mode of operation,
>   hence inverter.

Source: [IEE Explore - History of the inverter](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=476602).

Comment: Someone appears to have elves in their OCR, but the error is too small for me to fix (it should be "[1]" but I tried to delete it).

Comment: Thanks for that. I remember catching sight of 'Elf' in the corner of my eye but forgot to check it. Interestingly the original document is a scan but I'm able to select the text in the any of my browsers so I'm not sure where the OCR is occurring. Is the PDF providing both text and bitmap image in the file?

Comment: Increasingly these scanned PDFs have OCRed text built in. It was probably done by the scanner software (that's now our lunchtime discussion in work)