# 12 V load doesn't turn on with boost converter

Tags: batteries, dc, dc-dc-converter, boost, buck-boost

I'm trying to build a power source for my router during load shedding, but the router doesn't turn on when connected to any sort of boost converter.

I have tried five more different routers from different brands. All the routers turn off after they are connected to any boost converter. They run well with a wall adapter, other 12 V inputs, etc. Here are the diagrams of two setups.

### Set-up 1:

[image: Set-up-1]

### Set-up 2:

[image: Setup-2]

Here are the boost converters I'm using:

### Boost converter 1:

[image: boost converter 1]
XL6009 module

### Boost converter 2:

[image: Boost converter 2]
MT3608 module

Note: All my boost converters work with other 12 V to 24 V applications, yet the router doesn't get any power. The female barrel connector and boost converter connector are the same. My primary router is a TP-Link router with 12 V input.

Comment: Did you check if you're actually getting 12V ???    The 2nd booster shown has no bulk capacitors, that's kinda wacked - You almost certainly would need a couple hundred microfarad, those two tan colored blocks are ceramic caps, and maybe 0.1 - 10 microfarad at most.     What are the MAX CURRENT OUTPUT ratings of those two boosts and how do they compare with the rated INPUT CURRENT of your router???

Comment: Also, you can't look at your voltage sources as "pure sources".... THey're only going to be able to output a limited amount of current.  For USB, that's probably around 1A.  But you can't get something for nothing.  The power coming out can not exceed the power going in.   P=V*I    If the INPUT to your boost is 1A @ 5V, and you boost to 12V, then the maximum OUTPUT current you can get is 1A * (5/12)=0.4A  (Actually much less because they won't operate with 100% efficiency - You'll lose some power as heat)

Comment: You might want to read through https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/501176/2028 for additional help.

Comment: Bad assumptions on I/O impedances often are the root cause of DCDC problems.

Comment: @KyleB Thanks for your help. Yes, I get 12 V stable output. Also I have tried using 16V 1000uf capacitor on the output of the boost converter. But no luck. All most all the router I have tested this with, consumes less than 700mA, some even consumes only 300mA and the boost converters are rated for 3A and 2A respectively. Also the model number of the boost converters are XL6009 and MT3608 respectively. You can look at their datasheet if you need more information.

Comment: @jYelton thanks for the reply.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 , Thanks for the hope. Can you tell me bit more about I/O impedance? Or maybe a link to a good article?

Comment: XL6009 and MT3608 are part numbers for the converters IC and your ratings are based on some ideal circuit the manufacturers test with.   That's doesn't tell us what your little board is actually capable of.  If the inductors on your boards have higher DC-resistance, were poorly matched, or whatever, the IC's won't be able to operate with those ideal values.    You probably don't have an oscilloscope, so try this.  Get an LED and maybe 1k resistor, tie it directly across the boost output...

Comment: ... Watch the LED closely - If it flickers dim when the router resets, that demonstrates you don't have a stable supply and you're 'browning out'.  It won't guarantee your supply is stable if you don't see it, but if you DO that proves it's not.

Comment: There's a high frequency electric field around the inductors on your boost.  Perhaps that's interfering with the routers.  Move the boosts at least a foot or so away from the router, more if possible.

Comment: step up converters have high start currents on simple converters so not good

Comment: @KyleB thanks for your comments. I have done few new testings this week. The led doesn't flicker on boost converter. I have managed to turn on some of the routes with this boost converters. Adding a resistor in series with the routers makes the routers turn on. For some routers 5-10 ohms works fine, but for others 11-29 ohms are needed. Almost all the resistor gets hot and very hot after few minutes. Also few other routers doesn't even turn on, including my regular router.

Comment: I have successully used a MT3608 module to power multiple routers, but obviously, as mentioned above, it depends on the exact load requirements of the router. 
I also had trouble at first and could not figure it out. Turns out it was the DC barrel connector that had a slightly too large inner diameter and simply did not connect any power. A simply converter plug solved the issue for my TP-Link router, and its working fine:
https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/677547/power+adapter+port+may+be+damaged