# 5V to 12V converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a 5V 2.1A input. I have to power something with 12V 400mA.
What's the easiest way to do so? A NMH0509SC has a maximum current output of 0.11A. Will that work?

Comment: Why do you think it might work?

Comment: *NMH0509SC has a maximum current output of 0.11A.* yet you need 400 mA = 0.4 A. Please correct me if I'm wrong but 0.11 A is smaller than 0.4 A so you need more (0.4 A) than that NMH0509SC can deliver (0.11 A). So I don't think that will work. Instead search for "step up converter module" or "boost converter module". There are plenty of "Cheap Chinese" modules that can do the job. For example modules using chips like MT3608 or XL6009.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/501176/2028

Answer (score -2):

LM2596 should suit your needs. It's a buck converter.

Taken from Aliexpress:

> Input: DC 3.2V to 35V (input voltage must be more than the output voltage can not be higher than boost 1.25v.)
>
> Output: 1.25V to 30V DC voltage is continuously adjustable, high efficiency and maximum output current of 3A.

Edit: As @Bimpelrekkie said, the author needs a step-up converter. Which means they should use MT3608 instead.

Comment: The LM2596 is indeed a **buck converter**, also called a **step down converter**. That means that the **output voltage** will be **lower** than the **input voltage**. OP asks for a way to go from 5 V to 12 V. In my opinion that means that the output voltage will need to be **higher** than the input voltage. So a **boost converter** or **step up converter** would be much more suitable.

Comment: You're correct. Then MT3608 should do the job.

Comment: Please don't quote specs from that source - this is a pro site and although we cater for hobbyists, ali-express information cannot be relied upon. And, as pointed out, the 2596 is a buck converter. Pretty much wrong all round in my opinion.

Comment: Is there an alternative on reichelt.de or conrad.de? I can't find anything suitable on there.

Comment: "MC 34063 A" has 3-40V input and 1.25V-40V output. The datasheet says the output current is up to 1.5A.

Comment: LM2596 can be used if having +5V and -7V is an acceptable form of 12V (or if the supply is not shared with any other device)